# how to make the inserted data 4 digits in decimal part?

Tags: sqlite

I have create a db with

```
sqlite3  e:\\tmp.db
```

and create my table.

```
create table test(value decimal(8,4))
```

when i insert data , the data will contain many digits in decimal part than 4.

```
insert into test select  89.56/3 ;
select * from test
```

I got a number :  `29.853333333333335` ,how can i insert 29.8533 into test table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [SQLite Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), the `DECIMAL(M,N)` datatype will actually be stored as a `NUMERIC`, which will be converted by the SQLite engine as it sees fit to optimize storage.

Since you are inputting a floating point value, SQLite is probably storing it as such, and since floating point values cannot represent some values exactly, you are ending up with an approximation instead.

If you must store the value exactly with a certain precision, you have three options:

1. Use the `ROUND` function: `INSERT INTO test SELECT ROUND(89.56/3, 4)`, which will round to 4 decimal places.
2. Use the `STRING` datatype. SQLite will automatically convert it to a `NUMERIC` for mathematical operations.
3. Use the `INTEGER` datatype, and store all of your values multiplied by 10 000, ie. 29.8533 => 298533. Then you can divide again when you retrieve the value to convert it to its proper magnitude.